How can I prove the convexity of this function?
Let
$f(x, \omega) = x_{1} + x_{2}\cos \omega + x_{3}\cos 2\omega + \cdots +x_{n}\cos (n-1)\omega$ and $g(x, \omega) = -\log f(x, \omega)$.
The question is 'Is $g(x,\omega)$ convex when $\omega(\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}])$ is fixed?'
Somebody says that it is convex since $x_{1} + x_{2}\cos \omega + x_{3}\cos 2\omega + \cdots +x_{n}\cos (n-1)\omega$ is affine in the domain. However, I am curious whether it is still convex when some $\cos (i-1)\omega$-s are negative. I tried to prove or disprove, but the Hessian and etc could not be a help. Can anybody give a hint to prove the statement?

Yes, it is true even if some of the coefficients are negative. As a motivating example, consider $f(x) = x$ vs $g(x) = -x$. Both have convex epigraphs. To prove it, consider $f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y, \omega)$, and show it is equal (and hence less than or equal) to $\lambda f(x, \omega) + (1 - \lambda)f(y, \omega)$.

When $\omega$ is fixed, $f(x,\omega)$ is linear in $x$ (no matter those $\cos$ coefficients are positive or negative). Then, $g(x,\omega)$ is composed by negative log (decreasing and convex) with linear (can be considered as concave). So, use the composition rule, we can see $f(x,\omega)$ is convex in $x$.
